# vis.js Rolling mode on timeline stops scrolling when items are centered

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have a basic vis timeline with the following setup:

```
var container = document.getElementById('example-timeline');
var data = new vis.DataSet([]);

// Configuration for the Timeline as JSON object
var options = {
  rollingMode: {
    follow: true,
    offset: 0.5
  },
  rtl: false,
  zoomMax:30000
};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, data, options);
```

This is to create a performance monitor of sorts (like the Chrome Network monitor console) where items will be added to the data set dynamically (real-time). The idea is to have the timeline constantly rolling so that the last 30s (assuming no user zoom / movement) are always in view. I expect older events to roll off screen.

The rolling mode seems to work fine until the first event is added. Once the event is added, rolling mode will scroll until that item is centered in the timeline. Once the item is centered, the timeline stops scrolling. If I delete the record, the timeline continues scrolling.

It doesn't appear as though the timeline is letting items roll out of visibility.

JsFiddle for convenience http://jsfiddle.net/hae0k1ry/16/. The code snippet contains all the required configuration to reproduce the issue. I'm using version 4.21.0 of vis.js.

Comment: If you delete the items rolling works? I couldn't find it  working after deleting the items also.

Comment: It should. I just double checked the fiddle. Rolling works until an item is added. Clearing the item resumes rolling.